# How do I use RegisterWaitForSingleObject() to feed jobs to the thread pool?

Tags: multithreading, iis, asp.net-web-api, threadpool

I've read a number of posts about RegisterWaitForSingleObject and the main conclusion to all this is it's very easy to use this wrong. Hence my question.

The below is greatly simplified to keep the focus on RegisterWaitForSingleObject.

I have a cluster of several REST web apps (ASP.NET Web API2 if that matters) that each will get requests for jobs that take between 5 seconds and 15 minutes. So each request is saved in a SQL database.

Then when one of the web apps has an available background thread from the ThreadPool, it gets the next job from the SQL database, and processes it. When complete, it writes the result to the database.

When any of the web apps is asked for the status of a job, it reads from the database and returns the result if the request is completed.

My question is how do I use RegisterWaitForSingleObject to have it call me when a background thread is free. In a way that will create up to the max in the ThreadPool immediately, then not trigger until a thread is available.

This way I have all web apps running at full speed, but no requests pending waiting for an available thread when another web app has available background threads.

Comment: After observing days of posts from you, I wonder why there cannot be a farm of Windows service apps to conquer the challenge and you must stick to ASP.NET and IIS with all such crazy ideas to make things more complex day by day. Anyway, feel free to take your own approach and good luck.

Comment: @LexLi Yeah, the questions are because I keep coming at this from different directions, but I don't like any of the solutions I've thought of so far. I'm hoping that answers or comments I get from one of these approaches leads to a clean efficient solution.